# rsync 3.2.3 keeps crashing on Mac mini M1

Tags: macos, backup, unix, mac-mini, rsync

Trying to use rsync on a Mac mini M1 to backup from an external hard drive(formatted as APFS) to a NAS (shared as smb/cifs). I've tried a number of rsync commands but this was the most recent

```
rsync -avv --delete --info=progress2 /Volumes/FranBackup_6TB/FranArchives/Frans_Files /Volumes/FranArchives/
```

It starts running fine but after a while, maybe an hour or so it completely crashes the system and my Mac reboots. I've tried the `cp` command and that doesn't seem to crash. Below is the error message received after rebooting.

*edit* I failed to mention I had installed rsync version 3.2.3 via brew.

```
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xfffffe001d881df8): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 90 seconds (10122 total checkins since monitoring last enabled)
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20E232
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Fri Mar  5 01:14:02 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.1~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 50FBF6E680084E0B373849299AD93D92
Kernel UUID: 4C260D10-173B-3E11-A79B-9D423527AAAC
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.101.4
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000012de0000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0019de4000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000013920000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe001a924000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe001a9ec000
mach_absolute_time: 0x23633cd08d0
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x60a598b6 0x00055aa5
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x60a7247a 0x000cc761

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd4
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd4
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd4
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd4
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd8
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5cb20
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd8
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001ab5dfd8
Total cpu_usage: 62255544
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xfffffe001e811c68 kernel_task 91 4948330
0xfffffe1667076640 kernel_task 91 1248105
0xfffffe1666f91fe0 kernel_task 0 0
0xfffffe1667024000 kernel_task 0 3752511
0xfffffe166709d320 kernel_task 0 4969813

Panicked task 0xfffffe1666bd0688: 244626 pages, 475 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe001e811c68, backtrace: 0xfffffe306632f8b0, tid: 101
          lr: 0xfffffe001aa3a920  fp: 0xfffffe306632f920
          lr: 0xfffffe001aa3a704  fp: 0xfffffe306632f990
          lr: 0xfffffe001ab63338  fp: 0xfffffe306632f9b0
          lr: 0xfffffe001ab54b98  fp: 0xfffffe306632fa60
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9f37e8  fp: 0xfffffe306632fa70
          lr: 0xfffffe001aa3a394  fp: 0xfffffe306632fe00
          lr: 0xfffffe001aa3a394  fp: 0xfffffe306632fe70
          lr: 0xfffffe001b1ea974  fp: 0xfffffe306632fe90
          lr: 0xfffffe001d881df8  fp: 0xfffffe306632fec0
          lr: 0xfffffe001d8815bc  fp: 0xfffffe306632ff00
          lr: 0xfffffe001bddd668  fp: 0xfffffe306632ff20
          lr: 0xfffffe001bb568c8  fp: 0xfffffe306632ffb0
          lr: 0xfffffe001b13f550  fp: 0xfffffe306632ffc0
          lr: 0xfffffe001ab575c0  fp: 0xfffffe306632ffe0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9f385c  fp: 0xfffffe306632fff0
          lr: 0xfffffe001aafc2d4  fp: 0xfffffe405762bed0
          lr: 0xfffffe001aafe7ec  fp: 0xfffffe405762bf00
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9fcc38  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController(1.0d1)[1903B10D-E35E-3864-9842-4EE73CE97CD2]@0xfffffe001bb54000->0xfffffe001bb57fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[58B65D99-A7B7-316F-8E28-CEDEE98BBC3E]@0xfffffe001b348000->0xfffffe001b397fff
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[BEE7A0FC-B21D-32F4-8632-C669EA683887]@0xfffffe001d880000->0xfffffe001d883fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer(1.0)[2B2069CC-0C2D-3A5A-B4FA-D10F4C2D8371]@0xfffffe001bddc000->0xfffffe001bddffff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[58B65D99-A7B7-316F-8E28-CEDEE98BBC3E]@0xfffffe001b348000->0xfffffe001b397fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[BEE7A0FC-B21D-32F4-8632-C669EA683887]@0xfffffe001d880000->0xfffffe001d883fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[789544EB-168A-39BF-9FAB-1D8E60EDF2EE]@0xfffffe001ce54000->0xfffffe001ce57fff

last started kext at 13069821267: com.apple.plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin 940.4 (addr 0xfffffe001a524000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.4d18
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostBillboardDevice    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.100.114
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  436.100.4
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    11.0.0
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.100.11
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.AGXG13G   173.22.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   380
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.73.2
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.60.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCDP29XXUpdateSupport 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   311
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.plugin.IOAVBDiscoveryPlugin   940.4
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 940.4
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   980.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  405.39
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   300.6.1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  16.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.4d18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.4d18
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIPCI    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSB   1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    173.22.1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  173.22.1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   442.26
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 442.26
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    540.10
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 21.5
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.75.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    980.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.4d18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.4d18
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.7.0
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.101.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.101.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.100.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.100.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   290.7
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 332209 (Uncompressed 819888) **
```

Lot of variables here. Not sure if it's related to rsync, or Big Sur, or M1 chip or the smb/cifs share etc. Any ideas? Seems pretty simple what I'm trying to do. Just back up my external drive to my NAS.

Comment: I've filed a bug with the Samba team (maintainer of rsync) and referenced this post https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14962

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverting back to the default macOS default version of rsync (2.6.9) resolved the issue.

Comment: Which version and how did you install it, had the problems and that information has to be in the question.

Comment: @mmmmmm I installed it via brew and version 3.2.3 was installed. I followed the steps outlined in this guide. https://dev.to/al5ina5/updating-rsync-on-macos-so-you-re-not-stuck-with-14-year-old-software-1b5i

Comment: Same issue exists on Monterey! Need to use the old 2.6.9 version of rsync.

Comment: I wish I found this post earlier. I thought there was something wrong with my computer, so I reinstalled the whole system.

Comment: I encountering the same issue using homebrew rsyc v 3.2.7 while mirroring a local folder of 55k file to an SMB 3 network share. I'm on macOS v13.5.2. You might want to add the path to native rsync to your answer. It's /usr/bin/rync.

Comment: you may also want to try macports version of rsync, which is what I'm going to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The `rsync` that Apple includes in Big Sur is `rsync version 2.6.9 protocol version 29`. It's from circa 2006.

The current version of `rsync` is `rsync version 3.2.3 protocol version 31`.

You can install it from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or try [building it from source](https://rsync.samba.org), if you want.

But it's no surprise that a 15-year-old tool is having issues. I assume there is some sort of licensing that prevents Apple from including a more up-to-date version of `rsync` with macOS.

I would suggest installing a new version and trying again.

Comment: Thanks- forgot to mention that I have updated to rsync version 3.2.3 but still get this error.

Comment: Even though the OP forgot to mention they'd already upgraded `rsync`, nonetheless, this is a good answer for anyone else landing here trying to troubleshoot an issue with `rysnc`, as upgrading older utilities is always a good part of the troubleshooting process. +1

Comment: @fpolig01, Did you have the same issue with the **macOS** default version of `rsync` as well?

Comment: No. I upgraded rsync prior to running into this issue. Think it’s worth downgrading?

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest the opposite: try the MacOS tool, rather than the homebrew one.

Comment: Actually it is a big surprise that a 15-year-old tool were having these issues. A user-space program generating a kernel panic is a surprise in itself, but it would have been less of a surprise with a new, "unproven" tool rather than an old, tried-and-tested tool.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still exists, on the default shipping version of rsync, on Monterey 12.2. I’ve also found that the issue surfaces using ArqBackup targeting an SMB share for cloud backup.

What happens for me before the total system crash, is that the network link itself actually crashes and shows as offline, prior to securityd segfaulting, and then a barrage of keychain password prompts. This culminates in an unexpected total system reset/restart.

In my case, I’ve completely uninstalled homebrew, and the issue still persists. Happens on both an M1 Mac Mini and an M1 MacBook Pro. Hoping to do some testing on an Intel MacBook Pro this weekend.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/317996)

Comment: I realize it doesn’t answer it, but it does add a data point along with other testing that has been done. I’ve opened a feedback with Apple regarding this problem given I have it happening on multiple systems.

Comment: Answers are for answers to the question only.  Clarifying info can be asked using comments so please use that section.

Comment: Just a heads up that I’ve found that MacOS 12.3 has fixed the stability issues seen with SMB mounts.

Answer (score -2):

I have Macbook M1 Pro (Mac OS Monterey 12.4), and switching from default rsync to brew rsync 3.2.4_1 worked for me. I gave the command,

```
brew install rsync
```

and then located the location of the rsync binary installed (which was `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rsync/3.2.4_1/bin/rsync` in my case) and used the same to download the files, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The question says that they had installed rsync via brew - soi how does this answer the question?

Comment: This answer *seems* to be pointless. The *only* difference from the OP's question is that the OP installed verson 3.2.3, also via `brew`.

Comment: Upgrading to 3.2.4 seems a good step and then possibly opening an issue with the maintainer if there is none and you have a repeatable report